# mongodb atlas automatically creates collection which not exists

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, postman, mongodb-atlas

when i try to get all users in postman, it doesn't recognize my original collection which is filled with data and atlas creates a new collection named users automatically which doesn't exists and postman considers that collection only. i'm using vs code. How to connect postman with my original collection, please guide me

Comment: Please post screenshot of your issue

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your collections/ requests. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).